# Issue viewpager with shared fragment

Tags: android

I have 3 fragments in a viewpager (A, B, C). Each fragment has within it a fragment shared by all 3 (D) and contains a button. When I pass from C to B or from B to A I have the following exception:

*android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #0: Binary XML file line #0: Error inflating class fragment Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #0: Error inflating class fragment Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Binary XML file line #0: Duplicate id 0x7f0900c4, tag null, or parent id 0xffffffff with another fragment for...*

How can I solve?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the error is in your id "Duplicate id" so first make sure your id's are created on the right way.
Now i will go with you through code how to implement the viewPager fragment as maybe you could find what you have missed:

Create your 3 fragments A,B,C each of them has a specified layout as you want.

then you will create an Adapter to attach these fragments into the viewPager as shown below.

**MyAdapter.java**

```
public class MyAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {


MyAdapter (FragmentManager fm) {
    super(fm);

}

@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    switch (position) {
     //here enter a number of n Fragments i.e.(3 Fragments)

        case 2:
            return new FragmentA();
        case 1:
            return new FragmentB();
        case 0:
            return new FragmentC();
        default:
            return null;
    }
}//end getItem

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return 3;
}
```

**MainActivity.xml**

```
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewPager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
mViewPager = findViewById(R.id.viewPager);
    MyAdapter myAdapter = new MyAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    mViewPager.setAdapter(myAdapter);
```

then attach the view pager where ever you want...